# Filter Values in Google sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am going to have a spreadsheet where I need to look up a value in one column of one sheet and return the value in another column in another sheet. Here I have to display all the other column in the lookup sheet.

[image: Here I have to display all the other column in the lookup sheet.]

I have used `=filter(DEC_JAN!F5:F82,(DEC_JAN!F5:F82<65))` to return the value in another sheet but I'm getting only one column.

How can I show other columns associated with the filtered column?

Comment: Please provide link to sheet or code to some online tools/repository for testing purposes /or/ mark answer if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Change the range of your filter to the columns you want to return. Like:

```
=filter(DEC_JAN!A5:J82,DEC_JAN!F5:F82<65)
```